# Replace app package on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app

I recently updated to Windows 10 Home Build 10586. Some built-in apps, however, appear to have been corrupted. One example being MSN News:

[image]

I have uninstalled and re-installed these apps several times with reboots in between. I have uninstalled apps both via the start menu and via Powershell (`Remove-AppxPackage`).

I am the only user account.

How can I force the store to replace app packages when reinstalling built-in apps?

Comment: Doesn't `Remove-AppxPackage` require the location of the appx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate to `C:\Program files\WindowsApps` (take ownership if you haven't already done so by `Right-clicking on the app folder then left-clicking security tab -> change ownership -> select your user name -> apply -> ok`)
2. Inside the folder search for "bing news" delete any file with `Microsoft.BingNews_2015.709.2017.3396_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe` or similar, then run the app.
3. In the start menu, `right-click the app` and click uninstall.
4. Finally go to store and reinstall the app and search for updates on the store.

Answer (score 1):

As reinstalling the apps didn't work, you might rather need to repair Windows 10
itself, which also includes repairing these apps.

See this article from the Windows 10 Forums for detailed instructions with screenshots:
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Ensure you have good backups before starting.

Comment: Tried and it doesn't help. I believe my original backup media may have been corrupted.

Comment: That's certainly a possible explanation. You should download the latest installation media, especially in view of the 1511 update.

Comment: Since this is a mission-critical machine I'd rather not reinstall Windows altogether (again).

Comment: If you can only replace apps, then you could [Reinstall the Windows 10 Store](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/how-reinstall-windows-10-store) itself, then repeat the reinstallation of the broken apps. If that doesn't help, then I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Before I did that the store itself was broken as well. :(

Comment: Too much is broken on your computer. It might really be better to reinstall (again) from scratch, using a post-1511 ISO, being very careful with the additional products that you install. But for a mission-critical computer, I would really counsel using the ultra-stable Windows 7, rather than Windows 10 which still has quite a few teething pains.

Comment: Not to mention the unstoppable Windows 10 Update, which can break your server at any moment.

Comment: I would've selected 7 or 8 over 10, but money.

Comment: If the problem is that Windows 10 upgrade is free now, you may be able to extract the current Windows 10 serial number for future use, and downgrade for now to Windows 7. I believe that this serial number will stay valid for the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

---

Uninstall the app

- Then remove Appxpackage yourself manually (Remove whole data regarding the app).

  > C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.BingNews_xxxxx\

.

Then try installing the app again.

Comment: Apps no longer appear in this directory once uninstalled.

Comment: Check in "c:/Program files/Windows apps/"

Comment: @saichaitanya - Did you verify this answer would even worked before you submitted it?