# Deleted WindowsApps folder, how to reinstall apps

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, windows-store-app

Several of my Windows Store Apps (Photos, Contacts, and Weather) were badly broken on my computer so I tried a lot to make them work again. They didn't start and the event log recorded "Illegal remote procedure call". I tried the Control Panel's troubleshooter (didn't find anything wrong), several powershell commands (most failed with "couldn't register app, AppXManifest.xml not found", tried to give permissions to the "Admins" group and such things. However, none of these worked.

Which is why I booted into Linux and deleted the WindowsApps folder altogether, in the hope that the troubleshooter would now find an obvious problem and reinstall the apps.

However, it still says the problem can't be identified. Now how can I reinstall those apps? (This was not such a smart idea, I know.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace app package on Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/1018168/replace-app-package-on-windows-10)

Comment: Not the same question. I don't even have a store anymore.

Comment: Read this answer [Replace app package on Windows 10](http://superuser.com/a/1018970) especially the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simply copy the WindowsApps folder from another Windows 10 computer after giving the appropriate rights to my user account using the `icacls` and `takeown` programs. Now the store works again, but the problem I had before is also there again.